# Insertar a base da datos replicando información

Tags: php, mysql, insert

¡Hola!, Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo un formulario en el cual pongo el nombre de una Encuesta, ingreso una pregunta y selecciono mediante checkbox a las personas a las que se les hará la pregunta.

Problema:
Cuando selecciono a una sola persona me inserta de forma correcta la información pero cuando selecciono más de uno (2 o 3 personas) me inserta un solo registro correctamente y los demás quedan vacios y me arroja el siguiente msg:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\encuestas\nuevaenc.php on line 17

Mi idea es que se inserte 1,2,3, N cantidad de veces los campos encuesta y pregunta así como el evaluador o evaluadores, algo así:

```
Encuesta|pregunta|evaluador
Redes Sociales|¿Que red social usas mas?|Jose
Redes Sociales|¿Que red social usas mas?|Maria
Redes Sociales|¿Que red social usas mas?|Eduardo
```

Mi formulario:

```
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST["guardar"])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "encuestas");
    $cuantos = count($_POST["evaluador"]);
    $PContador=0;
    $query = "INSERT INTO encuestados (evaluador,encuesta,pregunta) VALUES ";
    $queryValue = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$cuantos;$i++) {
      if(!empty($_POST["evaluador"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["encuesta"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["pregunta"][$i])) {
        $PContador++;
        if($queryValue!="") {
          $queryValue .= ",";
        }
        $queryValue .= "('" . $_POST["evaluador"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["encuesta"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["pregunta"][$i] . "')";
      }
    }
    $sql = $query.$queryValue;
    if($PContador!=0) {
        $resultcon = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if(!empty($resultcon)) $resultado = " <br><ul class='list-group' style='margin-top:15px;'>
   <li class='list-group-item'>Se han agregado corectamente.</li></ul>";
    }
  }

?>

<form name="frmEncuestas" method="post" action="">
  <span class="success"><?php if(isset($resultado)) { echo $resultado; }?></span>
  <p>Nombre Encuesta: <input type="text" name="encuesta[]"></p>
  <p>Pregunta: <input type="text" name="pregunta[]"></p>
  <p>Evauador:
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Jose"> Jose
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Luis"> Luis
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Maria"> Maria
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Eduardo"> Eduardo
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considera que realmente existen:

- `N` evauladores
- `1` encuesta
- `1` pregunta

Teniendo esto en cuenta, podemos ver que el error se produce al iterar el arreglo de `evaluador`.
El primer evaluador (`$i = 0`) accede correctamente a `encuesta` y a `pregunta`, el resto **no**.

### Solución:

Una solución sería que `encuesta` y `pregunta` no sean arreglos, es decir:

- En el `HTML` le sacamos los corechetes (`[]`) del `name`.
- En `PHP` acedemos al valor de la variable directamente.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST["guardar"])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "encuestas");
    $cuantos = count($_POST["evaluador"]);
    $PContador=0;
    $query = "INSERT INTO encuestados (evaluador,encuesta,pregunta) VALUES ";
    $queryValue = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$cuantos;$i++) {
      if(!empty($_POST["evaluador"][$i])) {
        $PContador++;
        if($queryValue!="") {
          $queryValue .= ",";
        }
        $queryValue .= "('" . $_POST["evaluador"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["encuesta"] . "', '" . $_POST["pregunta"] . "')";
      }
    }
    $sql = $query.$queryValue;
    if($PContador!=0) {
        $resultcon = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if(!empty($resultcon)) $resultado = " <br><ul class='list-group' style='margin-top:15px;'>
   <li class='list-group-item'>Se han agregado corectamente.</li></ul>";
    }
  }

?>

<form name="frmEncuestas" method="post" action="">
  <span class="success"><?php if(isset($resultado)) { echo $resultado; }?></span>
  <p>Nombre Encuesta: <input type="text" name="encuesta"></p>
  <p>Pregunta: <input type="text" name="pregunta"></p>
  <p>Evauador:
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Jose"> Jose
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Luis"> Luis
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Maria"> Maria
    <input type="checkbox" name="evaluador[]" value="Eduardo"> Eduardo
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

---

#### Comentarios:

- Tu consulta es susceptible a [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597)
- Considera utilizar [`XDebug`](https://xdebug.org/) para depurar tus códigos.

Comment: He realizado lo indicado y ha quedado correctamente, te agradezco tu apoyo y por supuesto que tomaré en cuenta el tip para usar XDebug. Muchas Gracias.